# How to get sorted data from react-arborist tree

Tags: reactjs

I'm using https://github.com/brimdata/react-arborist for draggable tree but I don't know how can I get the sorted data back from it. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `useSimpleTree` hook to create a data and subscribe to data changes using the method described below:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Tree, useSimpleTree } from "react-arborist";

export default function App() {
  const [data, controller] = useSimpleTree(initialData);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  return <Tree data={data} {...controller}></Tree>;
}
```

You can experiment using the example data from the [react-arborist repository](https://github.com/brimdata/react-arborist#examples).
I have put together a simple working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/usesimpletree-fq23ry?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know whether it's possible to add animation when internal tree is opened?

Comment: I haven't used it before. In the [repository's issues section](https://github.com/brimdata/react-arborist/issues/74), they suggest using external libraries for such effects.

Comment: OK, thanks, I opened a new question here, mybe you will be able to help there as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77470659/how-to-use-react-spring-or-framer-motion-to-animate-unmounting-of-react-arb